# Assigning to 'NSObject<PushNotificationDelegate> *' from incompatible type 'AppDelegate *const __strong'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, pushwoosh

Im trying to implement Pushwoosh into my game its very simple guide but I'm running into this issue here:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on protocols. Basically, a protocol is a list of methods and/or properties that an object must (or may, in the case of `@optional` properties) have. You read `NSObject<PushNotificationDelegate>` in that error message as "any NSObject subclass that declares that it implements the methods in the `PushNotificationDelegate` protocol".

To declare your class conforms to a protocol, you write the name of the protocol(s) in between `<` and `>` at the end of one of its `@interface` or `@implementation` lines.

The compiler reads each source file separately, and all the headers you `#import` from that source file (read up on "compilation units" if you want to learn more). So if you write the `<PushNotificationDelegate>` bit in the `.m` file, only code in the `.m` file knows about it, because other `.m` files only see what you wrote in the header.

In your case, the `AppDelegate.m` source file *should* see that, but maybe you have another source file in which you set the same type of delegate that only includes the header for `AppDelegate` and thus can't see it?

Anyway, if you read this error message with this knowledge, you'll see that `PushNotificationManager.delegate` is declared as `NSObject<PushNotificationDelegate>`, and that's what your `AppDelegate` has to be to be able to assign it to that property. And the error correctly says that an `AppDelegate` may be an `NSObject`, but not a `PushNotificationDelegate`.

The advantage of declaring that your class conforms to a protocol is that the compiler will print an error message if you forget to implement a required method.

Answer (score 3):

Your AppDelegate implementation should look like this:

```
@implementation AppDelegate <PushNotificationDelegate>
```

in line 20.

This means that your AppDelegate conforms to `PushNotificationDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I need to conform the protocol in the header file to silent the warning. I don't know what I'm doing.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BaseAppDelegate.h"
#import <Pushwoosh/PushNotificationManager.h>

@interface ChildAppDelegate : BaseAppDelegate <UIApplicationDelegate, PushNotificationDelegate>

@end
```